# How to keep viewBox centered when "zooming" in SVGs?

Tags: html, css, svg, zooming, viewbox

Often I use the `viewBox` attribute to "zoom" a SVG element. Zoom is accomplished of course by using lower *width* and *height* values for the `viewBox` attribute - but the *x* and *y* values are tricky to figure out for keeping the scene centered.

Below is a snippet where `viewBox="0 0 100 100"`. *( x y width height )* This is my starting point. The scene is to scale and starts at the top left corner.

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://codepen.io/basement/pen/oepKxY.css">
</head>

<body> 
  <iframe src="https://s.codepen.io/basement/debug/zdpVyV/PNAvYLZmJRQr"
          id="grid"
  ></iframe>

  <div class="wrp">   
  
    <!-- SVG relevant code below-->
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
         viewBox="0 0 100 100"
         width="100" height="100"
         class="canvas"
    > 
      <defs>   
        <style type="text/css"> 

          circle {
            fill: #0ff;
            fill-opacity: 0.25;
            stroke-width: 0.25;
            stroke: #0ee;
          }

        </style>       
      </defs>

      <circle cx="37.5" cy="50" r="25" />
      <circle cx="62.5" cy="50" r="25" />
      <circle cx="50" cy="71.65" r="25" />    
    </svg>
    
  </div>
</body>
```

*( Viewable in full page. Snippets are responsive )*

### Zooming in

Changing the *width* and *height* values to `50` in the `viewBox` zooms the scene. However I had to adjust the `x` and `y` values both to half the `viewBox` dimensions: `25` to keep the drawing centered.

`viewBox="25 25 50 50"`

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://codepen.io/basement/pen/oepKxY.css">
</head>

<body> 
  <iframe src="https://s.codepen.io/basement/debug/zdpVyV/PNAvYLZmJRQr"
          id="grid"
  ></iframe>

  <div class="wrp">   
  
    <!-- SVG relevant code below-->
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
         viewBox="25 25 50 50"
         width="100" height="100"
         class="canvas"
    > 
      <defs>   
        <style type="text/css"> 

          circle {
            fill: #0ff;
            fill-opacity: 0.25;
            stroke-width: 0.25;
            stroke: #0ee;
          }

        </style>       
      </defs>

      <circle cx="37.5" cy="50" r="25" />
      <circle cx="62.5" cy="50" r="25" />
      <circle cx="50" cy="71.65" r="25" />    
    </svg>
    
  </div>
</body>
```

### Halving the width and height isn't consistent

Following the pattern of halving the *width* and *height* to center the scene:

`viewBox="12.5 12.5 25 25"` should continue the zoom and stay centered. But it doesn't stay centered. My question is what formula or technique does SVG use that I can always figure out mathematically what *x* and *y* value I need to center a specific *width* and *height* value in the `viewBox`?

**Note: I'm aware of libraries like [Snap.svg](http://snapsvg.io/) and [Raphaël](http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/). I'm avoiding libraries in an effort to understand the fundamentals.**

**One more thing: I'm asking if you already have a *width* and *height* value in the `viewBox` how do you find the center coordinates of the scene. Not vice versa.**

*External stylesheets were included for visual cognition. The only relevant code to this question is pertaining to the SVG elements.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your calculations are wrong.  If the width and height of the `viewBox` get smaller, the x and y values need to get bigger.

```
Initial viewBox:  0 0 100 100
Zoom X2:          25 25 50 50
Zoom X4:          37.5 37.5 25 25
```

To get the x or y values, you need to subtract half the new width or height from the halfway point of the last (or original) viewBox.

```
Zoom X2:  centre - newWidth/2
          = (100/2) - (50/2) = 25
Zoom X4:  (100/2) - (25/2) = 37.5, or
          (25 + 50/2) - (25/2) = 37.5
```

Another way to calculate it is to subtract the current width from the original width and divide by two.

```
Zoom X4:  (100 - 25) / 2 = 37.5
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://codepen.io/basement/pen/oepKxY.css">
</head>

<body> 
  <iframe src="https://s.codepen.io/basement/debug/zdpVyV/PNAvYLZmJRQr"
          id="grid"
  ></iframe>

  <div class="wrp">   
  
    <!-- SVG relevant code below-->
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
         viewBox="37.5 37.5 25 25"
         width="100" height="100"
         class="canvas"
    > 
      <defs>   
        <style type="text/css"> 

          circle {
            fill: #0ff;
            fill-opacity: 0.25;
            stroke-width: 0.25;
            stroke: #0ee;
          }

        </style>       
      </defs>

      <circle cx="37.5" cy="50" r="25" />
      <circle cx="62.5" cy="50" r="25" />
      <circle cx="50" cy="71.65" r="25" />    
    </svg>
    
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it worked well for my purposes: zooming while keeping the focal point at the very center point of the SVG element. But how could I adapt this formula if I first have a focal point. Such as `( 35, 67 )` and a level of zoom, such as 2X `50 50` in this case and then come up with the X and Y coordinates to keep that point `( 35, 67 )` in the center of viewBox? There is a whole unanswered ( and recently edited ) question devoted to this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45892233/centering-on-specific-points-when-zooming-using-svg-viewbox?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Did a little more testing and I found it only appeared off center because I mistaked the actual dimensions of the grid for the `viewBox`. Your solution is solid and works again in this situation. Thank you!

Comment: Awesome answer !! been struggling with this for almost two hours.

Answer (score 3):

Since the code snippet expired and I had to give it some thought on how to implement it I thought I would spare others from doing it and post a working code snippet.

```js
var svg = document.querySelector('svg');
var viewBox = svg.viewBox.baseVal;

function zoomIn(){
    viewBox.x = viewBox.x + viewBox.width / 4;
    viewBox.y = viewBox.y + viewBox.height / 4;
    viewBox.width = viewBox.width / 2;
    viewBox.height = viewBox.height / 2;
}

function zoomOut(){
    viewBox.x = viewBox.x - viewBox.width / 2;
    viewBox.y = viewBox.y - viewBox.height / 2;
    viewBox.width = viewBox.width * 2;
    viewBox.height = viewBox.height * 2;
}
```

If you implement a panning feature it will work with it too without any modifications.

Comment: How do I keep it centered if i want to zoom out 1.5x instead of 2x. When I replace 2 with 1.5 it's not centered