# Centering on specific points when zooming using SVG viewBox

Tags: html, css, svg, zooming, viewbox

All other code aside, this question only has to do with the SVG `viewBox` attribute at the end of line 8: `viewBox="0 0 100 100`.

The question is: What formula can I use to pick an arbitrary point and zoom in specifically on that point, keeping the viewBox centered on it.

For example if I alter the code to `viewBox="0 0 50 50"` the SVG will zoom 50% but it will be stuck centered on point `0, 0` - this is the point that will be centered. I can fiddle with numbers and find center points over time but my question is what formula could I use to keep it centered on a unique point?

**Scenerio**: If I know I want to zoom to double the size and set the `viewBox` dimensions to `50 50` How can I find the proper X and Y coordinates on `viewBox` to keep the SVG centered on an arbituary point such as `( 70, 74 )`?

How do I keep the `viewBox` centered on point `( 70,74 )` when zoom is set to `50 50`.

`viewBox( ? ? 50 50 )` - Center on `( 70, 74 )`. How do I find the missing X and Y values?

```css
circle {
  animation-name: pulse;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-delay: 0;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
circle + circle {
  transform: scale( 0.25 );
  animation-duration: 8s;
}
@keyframes pulse {
  100% {
    transform: scale( 2 );
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://codepen.io/basement/pen/qXMRxX.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrp">

    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
         viewBox="0 0 100 100"
         width="100" height="100"
         class="canvas"
    > <!-- How do I zoom 200% and keep viewBox centered on point ( 70, 74 )? -->

      <script xlink:href="https://codepen.io/basement/pen/qXMRxX.js"></script>

      <circle cx="70" cy="74" r="0.5" fill="#f46" />
      <circle cx="70" cy="74" r="0.5" fill="#f46" />
    </svg>

  </div>
</body>
```

Note how this: [How to keep viewBox centered when "zooming" in SVGs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45762516/how-to-keep-viewbox-centered-when-zooming-in-svgs)  question asks about keeping the viewBox centered only on the center point of the whole SVG. This current question is about how to keep it centered on ***a specific*** arbitrary point other than just the center point of the drawing.

**Note: I'm not really using any libraries in an attempt to understand the underlying math behind it for future projects. Thank you.**

*EDIT: The formula provided in the linked question is: `centre - newWidth/2`. But this doesn't seem to work here. Point `( 70, 74 )` is the center in this case. So for the X value that's `70 - newWidth/2` Because we are zooming 2X here we know newWidth is `50` ( half of 100 ). So `50/2 = 25`, `70-25 = 45` for X and `74-25 = 49` for Y. But `viewBox="45 49 50 50"` Is off center. Point `( 70, 74 )` is below the center and too far right relative to the `viewBox`. JSFiddle: [jsfiddle.net/dndvzj8f](http://jsfiddle.net/dndvzj8f/2/). What Am I doing wrong? The linked answer's solution doesn't seem to work here.*

Comment: The answer to the linked question answers this one. Why do you think it doesn't? Simply plug in whatever centre you want to it.

Comment: @RobertLongson Please see edit and jsFiddle included. I tried plugging in various values but the result is not centered. The linked solution isn't clear how to apply in this specific situation.

Comment: @RobertLongson You are correct, I did more tests and it turns out `center - newWidth or newHeight / 2` is the best way to approach this. I got confused at first because I didn't understand the formula well and then I mistook the `viewBox` for the dimensions of my grid drawing. Formula is solid and this question is a dupe. Thank you.